# add properties to a JSON object during iteration?

Tags: javascript, json, object, iteration

The Mozilla Dev Center says:

> it is best not to add, modify, or remove properties from the object 
>   during iteration, other than the property currently being visited; 
>   there is no guarantee whether or not an added property will be visited,

However, I have no need to visit the added properties until later. So is it safe to add them?

E.g.

```
var animals = {"cats":25, "dogs":15}
for(var key in animals){
    if(key.substring(0,3) !=="big"){ // no danger of referencing them
        var newAnimal = "big" + key;
        animals[newAnimal] =0;
    }
}
```

Or will increasing the size of the object confuse the "for - in" iteration?

Comment: do you want to add `'big'` prefix to every existing property?

Comment: If you iterate over the array returned by `Object.keys(animals)` you can be one-hundred percent sure that your newly added properties won't be visited. By the way, [there's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - no, that's just a simple version, The actual object contains details for game characters. Many of these face left. The code finds the left facing ones and creates similar objects with right-oriented data. The game then just calls "left" or "right" (or top, bottom, etc) from the same collection. I found this to be much simpler than trying to constantly change directions during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs don't say that the added propterties won't be visited, they say it's undefined.

So depending on the implementation, you may end up with a *bigdogs*, a *bigbigdogs* etc., resulting in an endless loop.
Or it may do something completely different, after all, it's undefined behavior.

To solve this, work with a copy of the object instead and add the new properties to the copy without mutating the looped object.

**Edit:** Looks like you are checking whether the key starts with *big*, missed that when I first looked at it. So you should be fine.

It is still good practice to avoid undefined behavior like this. This can easily come back and bite you when the code has to be changed at some point in the future and the reasoning behind the loop/check is not absolutely clear.

Comment: The question has `if(key.substring(0,3) !=="big"){ // no danger of referencing them` precisely to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, see my edit -- missed that line when I first looked at OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care that "there is no guarantee whether or not an added property will be visited", then you can do it.

If you want to make sure you won't visit them, make a snapshot of the properties before the loop:

```js
var animals = {"cats":25, "dogs":15}
for(var key of Object.keys(animals))
  animals["big" + key] = 0;
console.log(animals);
```

If you want to make sure you will visit them, use maps:

```js
var animals = new Map([ ["cats",25], ["dogs",15]]);
for(var key of animals.keys())
  if(key.slice(0,6) !== 'bigbig')
    animals.set("big" + key, 0);
console.log([...animals].map(a => a.join(': ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe to add them since you have check to make sure you wont end up in an infinite loop.

The "add" adds it in random place so the order is not something you can count on, but looking as you don't need to visit the newly created property in the same loop this should be fine.

I would suggest if you just want to add new property create a new object which will later replace the current object once you are done. Because that way it will have better performance.

Also won't drive the person who is reviewing your code nuts :). Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

## It's safe

After start the iteration, when

- delete an item before visiting , you not see it.
- update an item, you see the new value
- insert an item, you may or may not see it in the current cicle. But that was also safe.

### source

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in